# Including dynamic HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, include

I have PHP variables to place within an included HTML file. What's the best way of executing this?

```
//contents of file1.php
$variable1 = "text 1";
$variable2 = "text 2"
$newContent = include('file2.php');
echo $newContent;

//contents of file2.php
<p>standard HTML with PHP... <strong><?=$variable1?></strong></p>
<p><?=$variable2?></p>
```

This general method is considered OK but the actual code here doesn't work. Do I use file_get_contents() or include(), how do I execute the PHP within the includes file to output the correct contents?

Should I be using something like `HTML>>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is fine, and you'll find that most people use the same exact method. I personally wouldn't use PHP short tags (some hosts don't enable it), but that's a matter of preference.

**Edit:** As per your edit, it seems like you don't have short tags enabled. Check your ini (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). But you *really* shouldn't be using short tags, because as clownbaby mentions, PHP 6 will deprecate them. Even if you don't care about future proofing your code, they're still troublesome (which is evident because your code isn't working). Switch to `<?php echo $variable1; ?>` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Agreed - short tags are being deprecated in PHP 6.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is fine, even most frameworks use it...

regarding the use of short tags, some servers do not allow it, so here is a workaround I use:

```
if ((bool) @ini_get('short_open_tag') === FALSE){
   echo eval('?>'.preg_replace("/;*\s*\?>/", "; ?>", str_replace('<?=', '<?php echo ', file_get_contents("path/to/file2.php"))));
}else{
   $newContent = include("path/to/file2.php");
   echo $newContent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$newContent = include('file2.php');
echo $newContent;
```

You shouldn't need to `echo` anything here. Just including the PHP file should execute any code inside it and spit out the interpolated template to the page. Whilst there is such a thing as returning a value from `include`, it's a rarely used feature you can generally ignore.

As ekhaled said, you may need to enable short tags or replace them with the always-supported `<?php ... ?>` processing-instruction-style syntax.

However, it's important to `htmlspecialchars` every text string when including it in HTML, or you've got a potential XSS security hole.

```
<?php
    function h($text) {
        echo(htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES));
    }
?>
...

<p>standard HTML with PHP... <strong><?php h($variable1) ?></strong></p>
<p><?php h($variable2) ?></p>
```