# Is there something like <img src=X> but for text, not using ajax (and avoid iframes)?

Tags: html

Essentially I have lots of small urls with parameters. a requirement is for users to be able to generate reports by coding their own html page with their own layout. The reports won't be dynamic so I don't want to use Ajax. Are iframes the only way?

Comment: Can you use something on server side (PHP / ASP / Server side includes)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of include() in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928331/equivalent-of-include-in-html)

Comment: Here's another with what looks like better answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336569/include-one-html-file-in-another-html-file

Comment: And here's one with a PHP answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616834/including-dynamic-html-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX doesn't require that the report be dynamic.  You can go get the HTML and then set the innerHTML of a tag with the result.  If there were a hypothetical tag like

```
 <remotediv src="..."></remotediv>
```

It would pretty much do the same thing as this.

I believe that javascript in the HTML set to innerHTML won't run -- which might be the desired effect.

Comment: Plain Ajax can't do cross-domain requests which is a notable downside to this